# How to save html entitie into csv file when parsing data with beatifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Couldn't find any solution to save HTML entities into CSV file, for example script extracting this kind of data

```
<li>Key Switch: Blue switch&nbsp;</li>
```

output in csv file will look like this

```
<li>Key Switch: Blue switchÂ </li>
```

Any way to save HTML entities as it is displaying on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to save HTML entities. There are only five HTML entities that are actually vital in HTML: `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;` and the less important `&quot;` and `&apos;`. All the others are merely a convenience facility, not a necessity.

When writing HTML by hand, they can come in handy for entering a character that has no key on the keyboard, or to distinguish characters that would otherwise look the same in the source code, like the regular space and the non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`).

But - it's perfectly possible to replace those entities with the *actual characters* they represent, given that you use the proper character encoding everywhere.

And that is precisely your problem here. This is what happened:

- You downloaded the HTML file, encoding was correctly specified by the server.
- You used BeautifulSoup to parse it. In the process, the `&nbsp;` was converted to a non-breaking-space character. This is a normal part of parsing, every HTML parser does that.
- You processed the DOM tree and saved parts of it to a CSV file. You chose UTF-8 encoding for that file. The non-breaking space is represented by two bytes `0xC2` and `0xA0` in UTF-8.
- You loaded the CSV file again, possibly in another part of your code, or another application entirely (maybe Excel?) but you did not specify that it was UTF-8 (a multi-byte encoding).
- So the application used whatever "default encoding" is configured on your system to interpret the bytes in the file - I suspect Windows-1252 (a single-byte encoding) was used.
- In Windows-1252, the two bytes `0xC2` and `0xA0` represent two characters: `Â` and, ironically, the non-breaking space. In other words, everything up to this point was correct, it was *reading* the data the wrong way that broke it.

Ways to solve this, from most favorable to least favorable:

- Tell the application or piece of code that loads the CSV file that the encoding is `UTF-8`.
- Add a UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark) to the CSV file. Especially Excel might need this in order to function correctly.
  Python calls this encoding `utf-8-sig`, you could use that when you open the CSV file for writing.
- Save the CSV file in your system's default "legacy" encoding instead of UTF-8, at the risk of not being able to save any characters that are unsupported by that encoding.